# Is there any practical considerations to prefer one notation for converting vectors into slices?

Tags: rust, slice, notation

A vector can be de-referenced into a slice by either of:

- `let slice = &*my_vec;`
- `let slice = &my_vec[..];`

I prefer the second, even though its more verbose, I find it more clear especially when the statement is mixed with densely used operators, and where de-referencing has different implications depending on `Box`/`Vec`/pointer types.

On the other hand, it uses a redundant range.

I'd like to ignore code-style personal preference and focus on tangible differences. Do they ever compile down to different code for release builds?

Comment: There's also just `&my_vec` if the slice type is required (e.g. in a function argument, or for a return value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is strictly no difference after optimizations:

```
#[no_mangle]
extern {
    fn simple(ptr: *const u8, len: usize) -> usize;
}

fn take_slice(slice: &[u8]) {
    unsafe { simple(slice.as_ptr(), slice.len()); }
}

#[inline(never)]
fn take_vec_auto(v: &Vec<u8>) {
    take_slice(v);
}

#[inline(never)]
fn take_vec_deref(v: &Vec<u8>) {
    take_slice(&*v);
}

#[inline(never)]
fn take_vec_index(v: &Vec<u8>) {
    take_slice(&v[..]);
}
```

Leads to the following LLVM IR [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2434b4d5276d02e325a142b89776156e&version=stable&backtrace=0):

> ```
> ; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
> define internal fastcc void @_ZN8rust_out13take_vec_auto17h2827abd8ce79beacE(i8* %.0.0.0.0.0.val, i64 %.0.1.val) unnamed_addr #0 {
> entry-block:
>   %0 = tail call i64 @simple(i8* nonnull %.0.0.0.0.0.val, i64 %.0.1.val) #2
>   ret void
> }
>
> ; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
> define internal fastcc void @_ZN8rust_out14take_vec_deref17h66cf4ce954b36d1dE(i8* %.0.0.0.0.0.val, i64 %.0.1.val) unnamed_addr #0 {
> entry-block:
>   %0 = tail call i64 @simple(i8* nonnull %.0.0.0.0.0.val, i64 %.0.1.val) #2
>   ret void
> }
>
> ; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
> define internal fastcc void @_ZN8rust_out14take_vec_index17h77571b14bbdb120cE(i8* %.0.0.0.0.0.val, i64 %.0.1.val) unnamed_addr #0 {
> entry-block:
>   %0 = tail call i64 @simple(i8* nonnull %.0.0.0.0.0.val, i64 %.0.1.val) #2
>   ret void
> }
> ```

So it is mostly a matter of style, and style is subjective.

Comment: This is the correct answer. One shouldn't worry about small things like that. Optimizers are like really smart these days. Which is a good thing because it takes the burden of thinking about performance for every line of code from us. Measure and identify the problem first; you can still worry about micro optimization then :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell based on current nightly release-mode MIR, the first variant is preferable since it does one allocation less:

```
let mut _0: ();
scope 1 {
    let _1: std::vec::Vec<i32>;
    scope 2 {
        let _6: &[i32];
    }
}
let mut _2: ();
let mut _3: std::boxed::Box<[i32]>;
let mut _4: std::boxed::Box<[i32; 3]>;
let mut _5: std::boxed::Box<[i32; 3]>;
let mut _7: &[i32];
let mut _8: &std::vec::Vec<i32>;
let mut _9: std::ops::RangeFull; // not present in variant 1
```

However, I don't know how it would look like after further optimizations - those may be different based on the target usage.

Comment: I don't think we should be looking at MIR, since it almost doesn't perform optimizations. I would expect both variants to compile to the same assembly after the LLVM pass

Comment: That's the most probable outcome, but it's not feasible to verify this with LLVM IR / ASM, since without actual output _everything_ will be optimized away (especially in the release mode).

Comment: `RangeFull` is zero-sized so I don't think the additional allocation matters that much.

Comment: Strictly no difference at LLVM IR level (after optimizations).